# Error in making python2.7 file executable with official py2app instructions on a hello word program

Tags: py2app

OSX 10.14 (Mojave)
python 2.7
py2app version = most recent as of Feb 11th 2019

I follow the official instructions found here:
https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html

I'm trying to get it to make a standalone for a 'hello world' program.

Everything works until the last step, which is 'python setup.py py2app'. I get the following error:

"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 18, in 
    setup_requires=['py2app'],"

I did not modify the contents of the setup.py file, so they are as follows"

#

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['appp.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

#

Note that prior to this last step, I did indeed run 'rm -rf build dist' as instructed.

The error that I get is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 18, in 
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/**init**.py", line 145, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 838, in run
    self._run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1053, in _run
    self.run_normal()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1150, in run_normal
    self.process_recipes(mf, filters, flatpackages, loader_files)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1007, in process_recipes
    rval = check(self, mf)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app/recipes/six.py", line 113, in check
    mf.import_hook(nm, m)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1082, in import_hook
    q, tail = self._find_head_package(parent, name, level)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1182, in _find_head_package
    raise ImportError("No module named " + qname)
ImportError: No module named gdbm

Comment: Please share the complete traceback, the bits you share do not contain enough information to know what's going on.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question and put the whole traceback there.